# Error in code: 'return' outside function

Tags: python, excel

I don't know why.
   I just want to read the Excel file into the Python code. What wrong  with these codes? I need help. Thank you!
 #test2.py

```
import xlrd

fname = "sample.xls"
bk = xlrd.open_workbook(fname)
shxrange = range(bk.nsheets)
try:
    sh = bk.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
except:
    print "no sheet in %s named Sheet1" % fname
    return None

nrows = sh.nrows
ncols = sh.ncols
print "nrows %d, ncols %d" % (nrows,ncols)

cell_value = sh.cell_value(1,1)
print cell_value

row_list = []
for i in range(1,nrows):
    row_data = sh.row_values(i)
    row_list.append(row_data)
```

The error is:

```
'return' outside function (D:/pdf-ex/test2.py,line 10)
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using a `return` statement in line 10 .. `return` should be used *inside* a function, your code is not inside a function.

Add

```
import sys
```

at the very start of your program and  on line 10 *replace* the `return None` with

```
sys.exit(-1)
```

More information on [return](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement) and [sys.exit()](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html?highlight=exit#sys.exit)

Comment: I use the ".xlsx" instead of ".xls".                             Here some wrongs are.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/pdf-ex/test5.py", line 5, in <module>
    bk = xlrd.open_workbook(fname)
  File "D:\Python26\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 370, in open_workbook
    biff_version = bk.getbof(XL_WORKBOOK_GLOBALS)
  File "D:\Python26\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 1323, in getbof
    raise XLRDError('Expected BOF record; found 0x%04x' % opcode)
XLRDError: Expected BOF record; found 0x4b50